# hdd sometimes stop working then connected to laptop via sata dvd-rw -> sata ssd adapter

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

Does it look like drive or MB or kernel or adapter bug?
Drive works ok if connected directly to another sata port.

```
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854306] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xc010 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854316] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854328] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:20:90:0d:41/00:00:10:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 4096 in
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854328]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854334] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854338] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854346] ata3.00: cmd 61/e8:70:b8:be:c7/06:00:05:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 905216 out
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854346]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854350] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854353] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854361] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:78:98:0c:01/00:00:10:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 4096 in
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854361]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854365] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov 19 22:59:13 selfie kernel: [  467.854370] ata3: hard resetting link
Nov 19 22:59:23 selfie kernel: [  477.878339] ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
Nov 19 22:59:23 selfie kernel: [  477.878349] ata3: hard resetting link
Nov 19 22:59:23 selfie mate-control-ce[4486]: #012error raised: [load_xbel_store: couldn't load bookmark file [NULL]#012]
Nov 19 22:59:33 selfie kernel: [  487.929951] ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
Nov 19 22:59:33 selfie kernel: [  487.929959] ata3: hard resetting link
Nov 19 22:59:44 selfie kernel: [  498.453880] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Nov 19 23:00:01 selfie CRON[4964]: (root) CMD (timeshift --check --scripted)
Nov 19 23:00:08 selfie kernel: [  522.941391] ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
Nov 19 23:00:08 selfie kernel: [  522.941405] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Nov 19 23:00:08 selfie kernel: [  522.941408] ata3: hard resetting link
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113527] ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113538] ata3: reset failed, giving up
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113543] ata3.00: disabled
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113572] ata3: EH complete
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113619] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#29 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113625] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 08 d9 72 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113628] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 148468224
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113657] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113662] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113675] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113679] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 10 41 0d 90 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113682] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 272698768
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113715] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113720] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 05 c7 be b8 00 06 e8 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113723] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 96976568
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113735] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:977: inode #8520507: lblock 0: comm far2l: error -5 reading directory block
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113744] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3020359 (offset 0 size 438272 starting block 12122178)
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113749] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121815
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113759] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121816
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113764] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121817
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113769] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121818
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113775] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121819
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113780] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121820
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113785] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121821
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113790] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121822
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113795] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121823
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113800] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 12121824
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.113901] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3020360 (offset 0 size 466944 starting block 12122292)
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114032] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114037] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 08 d9 72 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114040] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 148468224
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114058] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114068] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 10 01 0c 98 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114077] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 268504216
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114165] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114175] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 05 c7 c5 a0 00 03 98 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114179] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 96978336
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114194] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3020361 (offset 0 size 471040 starting block 12122407)
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114790] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sdb1-8
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114809] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114814] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a 04 0a 68 00 00 38 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114817] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 973343336
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114849] Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114874] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114879] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 3a 04 08 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114881] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 973342720
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114886] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 973342720
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114891] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 121667584, lost sync page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114932] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 3020362 at logical offset 0 with max blocks 116 with error 30
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114936] EXT4-fs (sdb1): This should not happen!! Data will be lost
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114936] 
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114944] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1) in ext4_writepages:2897: Journal has aborted
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114972] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114976] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#4 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114978] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2048
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114984] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.114993] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdb1-8.
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115178] EXT4-fs (sdb1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115203] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115218] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115222] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115228] EXT4-fs (sdb1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115245] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115256] EXT4-fs (sdb1): ext4_writepages: jbd2_start: 1024 pages, ino 3020363; err -30
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115609] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 240123936, lost async page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115650] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 240132260, lost async page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115685] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 12058624, lost async page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115725] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 12059007, lost async page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115731] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 12059008, lost async page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115849] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 12059013, lost async page write
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115993] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1) in __ext4_new_inode:983: Journal has aborted
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.115999] EXT4-fs (sdb1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie kernel: [  528.116346] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): dx_probe:744: inode #8393817: lblock 0: comm far2l: error -5 reading directory block
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[1229]: Error calling Drive.Ata.PmGetState: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2derror_2dquark.Code0: Error sending ATA command CHECK POWER MODE: Unexpected sense data returned:
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[1229]: 0000: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[1229]: 0010: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[1229]:  (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie crontab[5012]: (root) LIST (root)
Nov 19 23:00:13 selfie crontab[5013]: (root) LIST (root)
Nov 19 23:00:31 selfie systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Nov 19 23:00:31 selfie anacron[5037]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-11-19
Nov 19 23:00:31 selfie anacron[5037]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  565.538891] scsi_io_completion: 9 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  565.538900] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  565.538907] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 10 41 0d 90 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  565.538909] print_req_error: 13 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  565.538911] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 272698768
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  565.538928] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:977: inode #8520507: lblock 0: comm far2l: error -5 reading directory block
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  566.080377] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  566.080383] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 10 41 0d 90 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  566.080386] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 272698768
Nov 19 23:00:51 selfie kernel: [  566.080400] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:977: inode #8520507: lblock 0: comm far2l: error -5 reading directory block
Nov 19 23:00:52 selfie kernel: [  566.763862] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:52 selfie kernel: [  566.763870] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 10 41 0d 90 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:00:52 selfie kernel: [  566.763873] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 272698768
Nov 19 23:00:52 selfie kernel: [  566.763895] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:977: inode #8520507: lblock 0: comm far2l: error -5 reading directory block
Nov 19 23:00:57 selfie mintmenu[1531]: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code12: Failed to write file “/home/unxed/.config/dconf/user.NXK8SZ”: write() failed: No space left on device
Nov 19 23:00:58 selfie mate-control-ce[6796]: #012error raised: [load_xbel_store: couldn't load bookmark file [NULL]#012]
Nov 19 23:00:59 selfie kernel: [  573.585149] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:00:59 selfie kernel: [  573.585156] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
Nov 19 23:00:59 selfie org.mate.panel.applet.MintMenuAppletFactory[1229]: Error calling Drive.Ata.PmGetState: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2deNov 19 23:02:34 selfie dbus-daemon[2822]: [session uid=0 pid=2820] Reloaded configuration
Nov 19 23:02:34 selfie dbus-daemon[1229]: [session uid=1000 pid=1227] Reloaded configuration
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470080] scsi_io_completion: 146 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470090] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470097] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d 00 00 00 10 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470099] print_req_error: 145 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470101] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953524992
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470143] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470147] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470150] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953524992
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470155] buffer_io_error: 77 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470157] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 244190624, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470459] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470464] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470466] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953524992
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470471] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 244190624, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470539] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470543] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#9 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d a0 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470545] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953525152
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470567] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470572] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 70 6d a0 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470574] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953525152
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470578] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 244190644, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470651] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470655] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#11 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470657] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470661] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470732] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470736] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#12 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470738] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470742] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 2, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470816] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470820] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 38 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470822] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 56
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470826] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470896] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470900] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470902] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 120
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470905] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 15, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470975] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470979] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470981] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2048
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.470985] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 256, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.471055] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 244190645, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:44 selfie kernel: [  678.471128] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 6144, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982188] scsi_io_completion: 91486 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982198] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982205] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#14 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982208] print_req_error: 91486 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982210] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982217] buffer_io_error: 91484 callbacks suppressed
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982219] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982317] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982323] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#15 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Nov 19 23:02:49 selfie kernel: [  683.982326] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132686] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132691] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132716] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132719] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132740] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132744] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Nov 19 23:02:50 selfie kernel: [  685.132785] sdb: detected capacity change from 1000204886016 to 0
```

Comment: tried switching from ahci to legacy in bios and disabling ncq completely as described here: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/550559
- no result.

Comment: looks like it was caused by wrong hdd caddy adapter setting.
https://img.mysku-st.ru/uploads/images/04/27/74/2017/08/13/9530fa.jpg